# Store the contents of a message which triggers a function

Tags: discord.py

I don't know where to start like most things, but for example.

A user says "foo", the bot stores the message, and then says "bar". The closest I could get was this:

```py
message = await channel.send('hmm…')
message_id = message.id
```

Though this stores the message sent by the bot, and not the user which triggered the function. It also doesn't store the message, just the ID. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My goal is kinda like Sx4's suggest feature.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) not sure exactly what you want but seems like you are looking for the on message event? Here is an example. You should replace `client` with whatever you named your bot instance.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user: # Avoids loops by checking that the message author is not the bot itself
        # Code in here will run when a message is sent
    await client.process_commands(message) # Runs all commands contained in the message
```

If you want to store every message, use something like this to set a variable that you can then do something with:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        STORED_MESSAGE = message.content
        # Do something with the variable here
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Or to respond to a message "foo" with "bar":

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        if message.content == "foo":
            await message.channel.send("bar")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```